# Java SAX parsing: What's wrong with this XML?

Tags: java, xml, sax

I'm trying to [validate](http://www.validome.org/xml/validate/) an XML file, but I get the following error:

> Can not find declaration of element
>   'xsl:stylesheet'.

This is the XML:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<xsl:stylesheet version='1.0' xmlns:xsl='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform' xmlns:msxsl='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt' exclude-result-prefixes='msxsl' xmlns:ns='http://www.ibm.com/wsla'>
      <xsl:strip-space elements='*'/>
      <xsl:output method='xml' indent='yes'/>
      <xsl:template match='@* | node()'>
            <xsl:copy>
                  <xsl:apply-templates select='@* | node()'/>
            </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:template>
      <xsl:template match="/ns:SLA/ns:ServiceDefinition/ns:WSDLSOAPOperation/ns:SLAParameter/@name[.='TotalMemoryConsumption']">
            <xsl:attribute name='{name()}'>
                  <xsl:text>MemConsumption</xsl:text>
            </xsl:attribute>
      </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Where is the mistake?

EDIT: I want to parse this XML in Java with SAX, but I get the following error:

> Element type "xsl:template" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".

How to get rid of it?

Comment: Your stylesheet validates correctly on my end.  There must be something wrong with how it's being read into your program.

Comment: @James How do you validate? By SAX?

Comment: I just copied-and-pasted it into Oxygen XML editor, which provides XML validation as a feature.  And eyeballing the XML, it looks okay as well.

Comment: But why do I get this error in SAX? :/

Comment: It's hard to tell from the information provided.  How are you feeding the XML to SAX?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are actually trying to validate your XSL as an XML document, it looks like that website requires you to point to a schema or DTD in order to validate the XML against it.  You can get a non-normative schema here: http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#schema-for-xslt.   Here's instructions on how to reference a schema from an XML file: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-tipsch.html

You could also check "Well-Formedness only," and check the document for well-formedness, if not actually validity.

Generally, any XSL engine will report any errors in your XSL document, so you don't need to validate it separately.

Comment: Yup. I'm fairly sure there's no real way to check an XSL 1.0 document for actual validity. Other than running it through an XSL processor, which as @James says, should do the job quite nicely :) @Ivan you probably just want to check for well-formedness.

Comment: Good point on v1 vs. v2.  I didn't notice it was a v1 stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

Your XSL is OK, don't worry.  Just that there is no DTD/XSD for XSLs 1.0.  no one bothers checking XSLT stylesheets (1.0) for validity.  "Wellformedness" is enough.

Comment: But the parsing is not working.. Check my original post, I edited it.

Comment: Is it really in a file or did you stick it in a string buffer.  You probably have some single/double quotes mixup or forgot to escape some char.  The second template looks like the most likely culprit. If you remove it, the parser will smile at you again.  The introduce the Xpath expression bits back little by little to find where the pb lies.